# Samsung S3 only boots into safe mode. Also plays a female voice reading everything on homescreen

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, safe-mode

Recently, my Samsung S3 GT-19300 somehow went off and immediately restarted itself into safe mode. I assume in safe mode there are limited thing that will function on the phone? But in my case nothing seems to be working. All I hear is a strange female voice reading everything on my phones' desktop.

I have restarted the phone several times following various instruction on how to turn off safe mode but all to no avail, the problems is still persisting. It has a funny icon of a hand telling you to stop.

Do you know of any way to fix this? I’d like to be able to fix this, not minding having to do a factory reset if at all possible.

Comment: You might get more response if the title is the actual question, instead of simply "Samsung S3 GT-19300".

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a screenshot? Also to deactivate the voice just go to Accessibility and deactivate Talk-back.

Answer (score 0):

Please go into your BIOS settings by completely shutting off your phone, and press power + volume down key. Send a picture of this. You can toggle between settings using volume. Try and press "Continue normal boot" or similar.